# How to redirect a full directory to another webpage page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So basically, I would like to know how to redirect all files within a directory to a page on my website. I would like to do this via my `.htaccess` file.

I have a directory, `directory1`, and it contacts many files.

I need to redirect all files within `directory1` to `www.mydomain.com/webpage.html`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this before any other rules in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^directory1/? http://www.mydomain/webpage.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @fizzix nope, no idea. You need to look at your error logs to see why

Comment: Crap, typo, my bad. Got it working. Although, my page now seems like it is constantly loading, even though it looks like it has loaded fully? Is this because the rule does not have a condition?

Comment: @fizzix not because of condition, for that you're best off using firebug or some browser console to see what it's hanging on.

Comment: I get no errors or anything unusual. It only seems to happen when your posted code is within my `.htaccess` file. Once I take it out, everything runs perfectly.

Comment: @fizzix with firebug (using firefox) if you open the "Net" tab you will get a very [detailed listing of what is being loaded, how long it took and what is hanging](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2aiJa.png) that will tell you exactly why it looks like it's still loading

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will come in handy in the future. For this case, it seems to be loading all the files within that directory over and over again. Would you like my domain name so you can check it out for yourself?

Comment: PS. My console got that large from all the files it was loading that it just froze my browser.

Comment: Also, I am testing in Google Chrome with the Developer Tools.

Comment: @fizzix well, is there anything in your other rules or at `http://www.mydomain/webpage.html` that could be causing a loop? Like it wants to keep loading `http://www.mydomain/webpage.html` over and over again?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not to sure. I am super new to `.htaccess` and avoid it if possible since my primary language is PHP. All I know is that if I remove that line of code from my `.htaccess` file it works perfectly without everything loading over and over. But once it is added, that whole directory is loaded over and over. Here is my domain if you would like to take a look http://candotruckloans.com.au/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 301 redirect first, it's the simplest and probably fastest method. Otherwise your solution will require mod_rewrite engine to be on.

```
Redirect 301 /directory1/(.*) http://www.mydomain/webpage.html
```

If that doesn't work try RedirectMatch, I haven't used either of these in a while myself so I'm just shooting from the hip by memory.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /directory1/(.*) http://www.mydomain/webpage.html
```

Comment: Neither seemed to work unfortunately. Although, I do already have my rewrite engine turned on for some of my other rules I have going on.

Comment: Managed to get your `RedirectMatch` one working. Although as I stated on @JonLin post, its like my page is now constantly loading?